# Speed up creating window when it contains several hundreds of widgets

Tags: python, optimization, qwidget, pyside2

I am running into the issue that creating a PySide window takes quite a bit of time (talking about several seconds here). I have a window and it contains lots of sub widgets. Each sub widget itself is build of a QWidget and contains several widgets. When running the following code and logging the time it takes to generate the widget, it turns out that this is quite time consuming. As an example, building a window with 100 sub widgets takes around 0.6 seconds and 1000 takes around 6 seconds. So it feels that the number of subwidgets to create increases the time to build the window linearly.

Is there any tip to hopefully reduce the time to create the window heavily? Or at least a bit?
Would it be possible to pickle the widgets so that they need to be created once and can be used the next time the window gets created?

Here is the code:

```py
import sys
import time

from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore

# Adjust this number to increase/ decrease the number of sub widgets being
# created.
NUMBER_ELEMENTS = 1000


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 700))

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.table.setColumnCount(1)

        self.table.setRowCount(NUMBER_ELEMENTS)
        for row in range(NUMBER_ELEMENTS):
            widget = SubWidget()
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, widget)

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()


class SubWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SubWidget, self).__init__()

        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel("My name")
        self.label_format = QtWidgets.QLabel("my format")
        self.label_frames = QtWidgets.QLabel("XXX")
        self.label_type = QtWidgets.QLabel("some type")
        self.label_size = QtWidgets.QLabel("some size")
        self.push_favorite = QtWidgets.QPushButton("hello")
        self.label_comment = QtWidgets.QTextEdit("something")
        self.label_comment.setMaximumHeight(80)
        self.label_comment.setProperty("style", "comment")
        self.video = QtWidgets.QLabel("my video")

        self.layout_main = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.video, 17)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_name, 20)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_format, 10)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_frames, 10)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_type, 10)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_size, 10)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.push_favorite, 15)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_comment, 50)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = time.time()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Main()
    main_window.raise_()
    main_window.show()
    print "Duration to build window: ", time.time() - start
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hace you tried with a `QTableView` and a `model` instead? QTableWidget are quite slow, and not well suited for these kind of things IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Saelyth. Yes, I think this would be a way. To be honest, I am only a little bit familiar with PySide's model-view architecture and wasn't aware that it renders a lot quicker. I will have a look at it. So far from what I see, model-view seems limited in the widgets to display. Yes, if it is only displaying text or an image, then this works. However, what I would need is a Label that refreshes several times per second and has a context menu. I am wondering if that is at all possible with model-view.